# Setting an appindicator's tooltip in pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I've built an appindicator with a menu using the following code:

```
self.ind = appindicator.Indicator("my-indicator", "indicator-messages",
                                  appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
self.ind.set_status(appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
self.ind.set_attention_icon("icon1.png")
self.ind.set_icon("icon2.png")

self.menu = gtk.Menu()
item = gtk.MenuItem("Foo bar")
item.show()
self.menu.append(item)

self.menu.show()
self.ind.set_menu(self.menu)
```

I want to add a tooltip that shows up when the user hovers over the icon.  I think [gtk.Tooltip](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktooltip.html) is probably the right thing, but appindicator documentation is sparse.  How do I attach a Tooltip to the appindicator?

Ultimately I am looking for this sort of behavior:

[image: appindicator with hover text]

Comment: probably self.ind.set_tooltip_text("app Tooltip")

Comment: 'appindicator.Indicator' object has no attribute 'set_tooltip_text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppIndicator do not provide tooltips by design.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-application/+bug/527458